# SelectedIndexChange Not Firing Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I'm hoping someone can help me as I'm beating my head against a wall trying to figure out the problem.  I have a databound CheckboxList that has the SelectedIndexChanged event wired up.  AutoPostBack is equal to true and ViewStateMode and EnableViewState are set to "Enabled" and "True" respectively.  I have other controls on this same page with server side events that fire just fine with no issue.

The weird thing is, the event SEEMS to be firing, as I can see the page reload when I check one of the items in the list.  However, when I set a debug point on the method, the debugger never breaks into that section and none of my code is firing (I've even tried having it write out silly messages just to see if the method is even firing - it's not).  Here's the markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="chkLanguages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" data-paramname="lcid"
                                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Here's the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
protected void chkLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do all the things
    }
```

What am I missing? I feel like it must be something obvious but for the life of me, I can't see it.

Also I should note this is in the latest version of Mono so there might be some weird quirk there that's causing the issue.

One final note, there are no errors in the console if I check the browser developer tools so I don't have any weird javascript stuff going on that's causing an issue.

**Update**
Since it's been asked, I'm posting the entire page markup and the requisite codebehind.

**Markup:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/pages/master/main.master" Inherits="Letters.Web.UI.searchLetters" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="additionalCSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/resources/css/letters.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/resources/css/bootstrap.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/resources/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css") %>" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="additionalJS">
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/resources/javascript/bootstrap.min.js") %>">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/resources/javascript/bootstrap-multiselect.js") %>">
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent">

        <section id="search-header">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="field-set">
                    <asp:Label id="lblTextString" runat="server" CssClass="data-label">Search for Letters</asp:Label>
                    <div class="data-control">
                        <asp:TextBox id="txtTextString" Width="100%" runat="server" CssClass="form-control searchable" placeholder="Contains Text" data-paramname="textString" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column-small">
                <div class="field-set">
                    <span class="data-label">&nbsp;</span>
                    <div class="data-control">
                        <button id="btnSearch" runat="server" class="search-nav-buttons" onserverclick="Search_Click">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

        <asp:PlaceHolder id="plcSearchResults" runat="server">
        <section id="search-results">
            <div class="filter-options">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="searchresults-headerstyle">
                            <th scope="col" class="header">Filter Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <asp:Panel id="pnlLanguage" runat="server">
                    <h1>Languages</h1>
                    <asp:HiddenField id="hdlLanguages" runat="server" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxList id="chkLanguages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" data-paramname="lcid"
                                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <asp:GridView id="grvResults" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                          AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Width="70%" GridLines="None"
                          OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging" >
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="searchresults-headerstyle" />
                <FooterStyle CssClass="searchresults-footerstyle" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-style" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Search Results" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="search-result-record">
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("LetterUrl") %>' Text='<%# Letters.Tools.WebUtils.HtmlEncode(Eval("Title").ToString()) %>' />
                                <span>(<%# Eval("Language") %>)</span>
                                <span class="keywords">Keywords: <%# Eval("Categories") %></span>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClss="language" Visible='<%# Eval("LCID").ToString() != "en" %>'>Language: <%# Eval("Language") %></asp:Label>
                                <div class="search-abstract">
                                    <%# Eval("SearchAbstract") %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </section>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>


</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

using Letters.Domain.Objects;
using Letters.Tools;

namespace Letters.Web.UI
{
    public partial class searchLetters : System.Web.UI.Page
    {       
        #region eventhandlers
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack) {
                this.BindResults ();
            }
        }

        protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            this.grvResults.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.BindResults ();
        }

        protected void chkLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.hdlLanguages.Value = this.GetSelectedItems (this.chkLanguages);
            this.FilterResults ();
        }

        protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> ();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (this.txtTextString.Text))
                parameters.Add (this.txtTextString.Attributes ["data-paramname"].ToString (), this.txtTextString.Text);

            this.BindResults (parameters);
        }
        #endregion
        private void FilterResults()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> ();
            if (pnlLanguage.Visible) {
                parameters.Add (this.chkLanguages.Attributes ["data-paramname"].ToString (), this.GetSelectedItems (this.chkLanguages));
            }

            //Finally, add the search string
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (this.txtTextString.Text))
                parameters.Add (this.txtTextString.Attributes ["data-paramname"].ToString (), this.txtTextString.Text);

            this.BindResults (parameters);
        }

        private string[] GetFilterOption(string delimitedValue)
        {
            string[] result = null;
            if (delimitedValue.Contains (",")) {
                result = delimitedValue.Split (new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            } else
                result = new string[] { delimitedValue };

            return result;
        }

        private string GetSelectedItems(CheckBoxList list)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();
            foreach (ListItem item in list.Items) {
                if (item.Selected)
                    result.Append (item.Value).Append (",");
            }

            if (result.Length > 0) {
                result.Remove (result.Length - 1, 1);
                return result.ToString ();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        private string GetSelectedItems(ListBox list)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();
            foreach (ListItem item in list.Items) {
                if (item.Selected)
                    result.Append (item.Value).Append (",");
            }

            if (result.Length > 0) {
                result.Remove (result.Length - 1, 1);
                return result.ToString ();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        private void PopulateFilters(List<SearchResult> results)
        {
            var languages = (from x in results
                            group x by new { x.LCID, x.Language } into counts
                            select new { Key = counts.Key.LCID, DisplayName = string.Format("{0} ({1})", counts.Key.Language, counts.Count())  }
                            ).ToList();

            this.chkLanguages.DataSource = languages;
            this.chkLanguages.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
            this.chkLanguages.DataValueField = "Key";
            this.chkLanguages.DataBind ();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (hdlLanguages.Value)) {
                string[] languageSelect = this.GetFilterOption (hdlLanguages.Value);
                foreach (ListItem item in this.chkLanguages.Items) {
                    if (languageSelect.Contains (item.Value))
                        item.Selected = true;
                }
            }

        }

        private void BindResults()
        {
            List<SearchResult> results = this.GetSearchResults ();
            this.grvResults.DataSource = results;
            this.grvResults.DataBind ();

            this.PopulateFilters (results);
        }

        private void BindResults(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            List<SearchResult> results = this.GetSearchResults(parameters);
            this.grvResults.DataSource = results;
            this.grvResults.DataBind ();

            this.PopulateFilters (results);
        }

        private void RegisterEvents()
        {
            this.grvResults.PageIndexChanging += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventHandler (GridView_PageIndexChanging);
        }

        private List<SearchResult> GetSearchResults()
        {
            return LetterService.GetSearchResults ();
        }

        private List<SearchResult> GetSearchResults(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            return LetterService.GetSearchResults (parameters);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is `data-paramname="lcid"` valid markup ?

Comment: Yes - it's an HTML5 parameter.  All ASP.NET controls support this type of markup (I use it elsewhere on the page with no problem).

Comment: set a break point in page_load.check if it is firing

Comment: Yes, Page_Load is firing and IsPostBack = true (as expected).  But my event handler doesn't seem to be firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to find the exact cause to the problem.  Every other type of control was able to post back events and I could properly handle their events server-side. I ended up working around this particular issue by ripping out the CheckBoxList and replacing it with a gridview that used an item template to store the value in a hidden field and display the checkbox where I could then handle the OnCheckedChanged event (see code below).  This worked brilliantly.

**Markup**

```
 <asp:GridView id="grvLanguages" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="false" 
               AllowSorting="false" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" data-paramname="languages" >
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField id="hdlValue" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Key") %>' />
                <asp:CheckBox id="chkDisplay" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void chkLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.hdlLanguages.Value = this.GetSelectedItems (this.grvLanguages);
        this.FilterResults ();
    }
```

I'm guessing the problem is probably some weird, esoteric bug in the Mono framework.  Like I said, I don't have a problem with ANY other controls (I tested quite a few - all of their server side events handled just fine); it was just a problem with the CheckBoxList.